# Strophe anonymous login getting Error

Tags: javascript, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I want to ANONYMOUSLY Login to Openfire server from my application, where i have used strophe library.

I have enables Openfire Anonymous Login option.

In my code:

```
    connection.connect(null,
               null,
               onConnect);
```

I did this. As i understand it should work, what am i doing wrong??..im getting following in Firebug.

Type Error: bare is null
[Break On This Error]

```
    if (bare.indexOf("@") < 0) {
```

Answer (score 3):

you should pass domain name without userid

```
connection.connect('yourxmppdomain.com',null, onConnect);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following answer is taken from a question in Google groups answered by Jack Mottiff (one of the authors of Strophe library)

((
The correct way of doing it is to set your JID to the domain only. No
local part (user portion) of the JID means connect anonymously if
supported.

Note that if you don't supply a domain, Strophe has no way to know
which server to contact!

jack.
))

[link to Google groups answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/strophe/I0J-xsBsPt8/6_dhDe2q3vcJ)